# Xcode fbsdk not showing in Libraries folder - React native

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to add [fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) in an Xcode project but I'm not seeing RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj in the libraries folder in the poject:

[image]

What is the step that causes the library to be in that list?

Comment: `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`

Comment: @bennygenel Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. glad that it worked